Movement world create with fixed 3D objects in Gazebo (SDF or World file)
I am using gazebo sim (new version) with ROS2. I normally create a world with fixed 3D objects. Not only that, but I need to create moveable 3D objects to Gazebo Sim.
Examples:

Elevator
Door (can open and close)
Fan (rotation on and off)
Lidar Rotation (rotating on and off)
Escalator
Travelator
Blender

I have humanoid robot and I need to create application task and simulate in Gazebo Sim.
Application Examples:

Elevator - humanoid robot come and click door open button and go inside then go up levels.
Door (can open and close) - humanoid robot come and open the door to go inside the home.
Fan (rotation on and off) - humanoid robot on fan then rotate it with air pressure

How can I create moveable 3D objects like mention above? Any example codes and applications video or documents for those.
I use Solidworks and Blender for 3D world design.

Have a look at open-rmf here and here
and its demos.
EDIT:
Based on your comment I conclude open-rmf might be too broad for what you are looking for.
Are you aware of the Gazebo Sim example world repository?
E.g. there is an elevator example.
For more examples, see also this threaed on the Gazebo community discourse.

Thank you for sharing this but not sure how to make world with above mention things.

What exactly is it that you not understand from the given examples?

I added some more references to my answer.

Thank you very much for the information. I like to learn more complex things. Please share if have some more.
